# Convert Microsoft Works database files to something that can be read in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, xls, microsoft-works

I have many .wdb files created with Microsoft Works. I need to open them but I don't have Microsoft Works.

Can anyone recommend a way to open the files in Excel?

Comment: which version of excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a free solution from Works 3 or 4, try [Works Database Converter](http://www.codealchemists.com/worksdatabaseconverter/).

> This application converts old
>   Microsoft Works Database (*.wdb) files
>   (e.g. MS Works 3 and 4) into a
>   spreadsheet compatible with all
>   versions of Microsoft Excel. The data
>   extraction is done on a 'best-effort'
>   basis, which works reasonably well
>   provided that you only have one table
>   of data per file that you process.

You just need java installed.

Comment: I tried the program, and I saw that it will not handle correctly rows where there are calculated columns, or at least, the free version of the program has that problem.